# ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded after configuring toplink to use bind variables

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, toplink

I have an application that uses Toplink for persistence and Oracle database. Recently I have had performance problems, especially on the db/query level. I have a big piece of logic in a bunch of triggers and stored procedures, badly written, with workarounds for the mutating trigger problem. The application is in production for a few years now, and rewriting this code the last solution, considering the bureaucracy of getting approval for a new release and other higher priorities. So I am looking for a quick fix.

One solution to improve the performance is to use bind variables. My problem is that after adding bind-all-variables and cache-all-statements in sessions.xml in toplink, on a certain UI, that triggers the crappy code, and worked just fine before making this config change, I get this error:

ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded

My questions are: why is it showing this error only after I add the bind-variable setting? What can I do to make it work with bind variables, without changing the crappy code?

Comment: do you have cursor_sharing turned on?

Comment: what happens if you set: alter session set cursor_sharing=exact;

Comment: The funny thing is that this doesn't happen on my dev and local machine, but it does happen on the stage machine. I even connected my local environment to the stage database, and I do NOT have this error. So I'm thinking it may be a jdbc driver problem.

Answer (score 2):

"with workarounds for the mutating trigger problem"

That sounds scary as most of those workarounds revolve around autonomous transactions which (a) don't work particularly well and (b) probably count as recursive SQL.

On the other hand, having logic in PL/SQL generally means the problem won't be bind variables, as you need to make a big effort in PL/SQL to not use binds.

In this case, I'd say your time is better spent on addressing/replacing any mutating table workarounds with a solid base rather than bind variable issues.